# HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode

Tags: json, python-3.4, urllib

I was getting the following error initially when I was trying to run the code below-

```
Error:-the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' 

import urllib.request
import json
search = '230 boulder lane cottonwood az'
search = search.replace(' ','%20')
places_api_key = 'AIzaSyDou2Q9Doq2q2RWJWncglCIt0kwZ0jcR5c'
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query='+search+'&key='+places_api_key
json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
for item in  data ['results']:
     print(item['formatted_address'])
     print(item['types'])
```

After making some troubleshooting changes like:-

```
 json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 obj = json.load(json_obj)
 data = json_obj .readall().decode('utf-8')

 Error - 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I am getting the error above, I have tried multiple posts on stackoverflow nothing seem to work. I have uploaded the entire working code if anyone can get it to work I'll be very grateful. What I don't understand is that why the same thing worked for others and not me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`urllib.request.urlopen` returns an `HTTPResponse` object which cannot be directly json decoded (because it is a bytestream)

So you'll instead want:

```
# Convert from bytes to text
resp_text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
# Use loads to decode from text
json_obj = json.loads(resp_text)
```

However, if you print `resp_text` from your example, you'll notice it is actually xml, so you'll want an xml reader:

```
resp_text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
(Pdb) print(resp_text)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
...
```

#### update (python3.6+)

In python3.6+, `json.load` can take a byte stream (and `json.loads` can take a byte string)

This is now valid:

```
json_obj = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
```

Comment: I tried following: 
    `json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')`
    `data = json.load(json_obj)`
Now its saying:
    `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: I am an idiot using wrong URL, I have fixed it thanks a lot @Anthony Sottile

Comment: hey @Uasthana how did you fix the "str object has no object read" error? I am getting the same error. My URL is correct. then why this error?

Comment: @rohitnair Hi I was actually using the wrong URL which was returning data in xml format instead of json, changing it solved the problem for me. I am not quite sure what it could be in your case unless you post the code. thanks

Comment: @Uasthana I was using `json.load()` instead of loads(). Changing it automatically solved the problem. Although my work is done, I still couldnt understand what magic `loads()` has over `load` which serves the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: `loads` is "load from string" whereas `load` is "load from file"

Comment: @AnthonySottile you are THE savior